# Google Apps Script Googleフォームに関して

Tags: javascript

まったくプログラミング知識のない者です。
拙い質問かと思いますが、どうか助けていただきたいです。

今、作成しようとしているのは
「Googleフォームを問い合わせフォームとして使用し、問い合わせが寄せられたら、特定のメールアドレスに転送する。
転送されたメールに対して返信すると、Googleフォームで問い合わせた方へメールが届く（問い合わせに返信出来る）」
という仕組みです。

Googleフォームを作成して、スプリクトエディタに下記のようなスプリクトを記載しました。

```
function submitForm(e){ 
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses(); 
  var message = '';
  var report = itemResponses[0].getResponse();

  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) { 
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i]; 
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(); 
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse(); 

    if (question == 'Googleフォームの項目名（氏名）'){
      var username = answer;
    }
    if (question == 'Googleフォームの項目名（メールアドレス）'){
      var usermail = answer;
    }

    message += (i + 1).toString() + '. ' + question + ': ' + answer + '\n'; 
  } 


  /* 管理者宛メール送信設定 */
  var address = '★自分のメールアドレス★'; 
  var title = '【お問い合わせを受信しました】'; 
  var content = '下記の内容で回答を受信しました。\n\n'
  + message
  + '\n\n'
  + '※このメールはGoogleフォームからの自動送信メールです。'; 
  var options = {from: address, name: '●●'};

  GmailApp.sendEmail(address, title, content, options);


  /* ユーザー宛メール送信設定 */
  var title2 = '【お問い合わせを受け付けました】'; 
  var content2 = username 
  + ' 様\n\n'
  + '下記の内容にてお問い合せを受け付けいたしました。\n\n'
  + message 
  + '\n\n※このメールはGoogleフォームからの自動送信メールです。'; 

  GmailApp.sendEmail(usermail, title2, content2, options); 


}
```

すると、自分のメールアドレスを
gmailで設定するときちんと転送されますが、
gmail以外で設定すると転送されません。
Googleフォームは転送先がgmailでないと対応出来ないのでしょうか。
それとも、スプリクトを編集する事で解決出来ますか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Scriptからのメール送信は、Gmailで送信可能なメールアドレスのみが指定できるようです。(Gmailを使用しているため)

もし自分の所有している別アドレスをFromに設定したい場合、そのアドレスをGmailのエイリアスアドレスとして設定すると利用可能なようです。

[[Google Apps Script]別のアドレスからメールを送信する。 | 初心者備忘録](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=4441)